# in vscode,how to run a spring(maven) project,dont tell me its stupid,i like the ui

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, visual-studio-code

I have tried this code:

```
maven spring-boot:run
```

It worked but when i click f5 software doesn't work and raise a error

> 报错java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication

under is some code of json:

```
{
    // 使用 IntelliSense 了解相关属性。 
    // 悬停以查看现有属性的描述。
    // 欲了解更多信息，请访问: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [


/*

        */
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Launch Current File",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "${file}"
        },
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Launch DemoApplication",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "com.example.demo.DemoApplication",
            "projectName": "demo",

        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an existing maven spring boot project. Now I am using VS code for running it, It is working.

You do this by following these steps

1. Open VS Code>File>Open Folder>[Select the maven project]>(Click on **OK** button)
2. VS code will open the project, Now in lower Right corner VS will ask you to install some extensions click on **yes**. (I installed Java Extension Pack & Java Extension Guide
   ).
3. Go to the Class containing main method and Run the project(either press ctrl F5 or click on Run button on the ton navigation bar and select **Run Without Debugging**).[image: My running Maven java project in VS Code]

Comment: it doesn‘t work，d:; cd 'd:\Ds\projects\demo'; & 'c:\Users\˽ݳ\.vscode\extensions\vscjava.vscode-java-debug-0.31.0\scripts\launcher.bat' 'D:\Users\˽ݳ\.jdks\openjdk-15.0.2\bin\java.exe' '-XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages' '-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8' '@C:\Users\˽ݳ\AppData\Local\Temp\cp_4dz931xc7dxe9xsm3ovkw5uj8.argfile' 'com.example.demo.DemoApplication' 
                                                                   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
        at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10)

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 1 more

Comment: i didn't find the plugin 'Java Extension Guide'.?

Comment: I used this for initializing the project :
https://start.spring.io/

And followed this  tutorial for creating the project. 
https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

Extension was suggested by the VS Code.